# How can I check if Animator ended playing specific State animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This way it's getting inside all the time while the animation state is playing :

```
void Update()
    {
        if (this.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Stand Up"))
        {
            string tt = "";
        }
    }
```

So I tried to add ! to check if it false :

```
void Update()
    {
        if (!this.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Stand Up"))
        {
            string tt = "";
        }
    }
```

but this way it's never getting inside even if the state animation finished playing.

I have one Base Layer in the animator controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOTE: The solution below is only really relevant if your animation isn't looping and I assume "StandUp" is non-looping.  Otherwise, the event will be raised every time the animation loops.***

In my opinion, you'd be better off raising an animation event.

You can raise an event from the specific animation in question by adding an event marker to the animation timeline.

[image: Creating an animation event]

Then when you click on the event marker at the top of the timeline, you will see some options in the inspector.

[image: Register event handler]

Then, you will need to supply a name for the event handler that you want to handle this event e.g MyEventRaised and attach a script to the object that has you animator component.

[image: Add animation event handler script]

Inside that script you can add the handler that you want for the event.

```
using System;

public class MySpriteEventHandlerScript:MonoBehaviour 
{
    public EventHandler MyEventHandler;

    public void MyEventRaised()
    {
        MyEventHandler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Then, in the any script that you want to respond to the event that you've created, you can just get a reference to the event handler script attached to your animated object and register some code with the MyEventHandler event handler.

```
private MySpriteEventHandlerScript _MyEventHandlerScript;

void Start() 
{
    _MyEventHandlerScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MySprite").GetComponent<MySpriteEventHandlerScript>();
    // Register some code to do something when the handler is invoked
    _MyEventHandlerScript.MyEventHandler += TheCodeToRun;
}

// Create the necessary method in your class
private void TheCodeToRun() 
{
    Debug.Log("The animation event has happened!");
}
```

Alternatively, you can just add all your handler code inside the MyEventRaised method  which is fine if you just want to do something simple but is a bit of an anti-pattern.